# Starting a loop part way through

Tags: c++, loops

If I have a conditional loop that should behave as if it starts part way through, what would be considered the best way to code this? Is code including a `goto` like the following snippet considered acceptable?

```
goto first_itr;
do {
  doSomeStuff();
first_itr:
  doSomeOtherStuff();
} while(condition);
```

The apparently less efficient alternative I can see is to introduce a flag and a conditional around `doSomeStuff();`, producing the following:

```
bool first = true;
do {
  if(first)
    first = false;
  else
    doSomeStuff();
  doSomeOtherStuff();
} while(condition);
```

This is the approach I normally use in this situation. Can a compiler be relied upon to ameliorate this by effectively transforming it into the first snippet?

Other alternatives I can think of that avoid the `goto` and the conditional would involve duplicating code, but that seems like a worse code smell than a `goto`.

Also, would the answer be different if the loop is performance critical, with the overhead of an extra conditional noticeably reducing performance?

Comment: `goto` is a tool of last resort, not the first thing you reach for. It's a very heavy-handed solution.

Comment: @tadman It was exactly this moral dilemma (Thou shalt not use `goto` etc.) that made me ask this question. To me it seemed like a choice between possible inefficiency and raptor-summoning evil (http://xkcd.com/292/). Luckily Kerrek SB has provided a way out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe like this:

```
for (;;)
{
    doSomeOtherStuff();
    if (!condition) break;
    doSomeStuff();
}
```

---

If A=`doSomeStuff();`, B=`doSomeOtherStuff();`, and c denotes the condition test, then we want to code

```
BcABcABcABcABc ...
```

this can either be done by looping over blocks of `ABc` (and somehow avoiding `A` in the first iteration) as in the question or blocks `BcA` as in this solution. The advantage of this solution over all others is that it avoids code repetition which is notorious to maintain.

Comment: This would still execute both functions in the first iteration, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @ZacHowland you do. The iterations in your code end at the conditions and begin with `doSomeStuff`. The iterations in this code begin with `doSomeOtherStuff`. Essentially, in this code, the last iteration is stopped half-way through, but without an additional branch.

Comment: @Walter The OP is asking how he can start a loop and skip over a function call in the first iteration ... not how he can end it by skipping over one in the last iteration.

Comment: @Walter Not always.  For example, if each iteration is operating on a specific point in an array, then `B|AB` would operate on the 0th and 1st elements in B and AB, respectively, while `BA|BA` would have have both functions operate on both elements.

Comment: @ZacHowland **NO** the OP has no loop variable which could point anywhere, so my analogy (AB..ABA) is **absolutely correct**. Any loop variable must be carried and incremented by the loop body, i.e. `doSomeStuff` or `doSomeOtherStuff`.

Comment: @Walter you are making assumptions about pseudo-code and countering any assertions to the contrary that they do not match your assumptions.  My point is that you cannot make such assumptions, and I gave you an example for when your assertion would break.

Comment: @ZacHowland the only *pseudo-code* here is `doSomeStuff`, `condition` and `doSomeOtherStuff`, the rest, in particular the loop and the order of execution is not. I make no assumptions that could be broken by any implementation of these pseudo codes.

Comment: @Walter:  You are assuming that running `BA` in a single iteration is equivalent to running `B|A` in two separate iterations.  While that is possible (e.g. if you are simply running the same functions X and X-1 numbers of times), there are cases where it is not possible (e.g. when you are iterating over an array).

Comment: @ZacHowland *You are assuming that running BA in a single iteration is equivalent to running B|A in two separate iterations* indeed they are. There is absolutely **nothing** in the code that can break that. It would be different, if the loop has an index variable, but alas, it doesn't! However, in this case, you simply apply the increment before the condition and all is well.

Comment: @Walter:  You are assuming that the functions do not contain them.  I'm only making the assumption that the OP wanted these functions run in a particular order.  You are assuming you can change the order.  Without more information, you cannot dismiss other solutions, and your explanation is lacking without stating that assumption.

Comment: @ZacHowland I didn't assume anything about the pseudo-code function nor did I change the order! you got that absolutely wrong, Zac. I actually edited this answer to highlight this point. If you still insist, proof it by giving an example of the pseudo code functions (but without altering the loop constructs) that would break the equivalence to the OP question.

Comment: If the functions are called in different iterations, you have changed the order.  I've already pointed that out, so if you don't see it, it is your problem.  But you should realize that having a function call that is not part of the loop outside the loop is not code duplication.  Many times, it can actually make your code *more clear* as other developers can easily see you are doing something different for a specific iteration.

Comment: Code duplication is whenever you have block of code, and be it a single statement, duplicated. This is always harder to maintain, since *all* instances of the code block must be independently maintained by the programmer.

Comment: So I'm guessing you only ever call `std::sort` once in any application you write ... because you wouldn't want to duplicate the call to that function, right?

Comment: This answer neatly sidesteps code duplication and `goto` whilst maintaining the original semantics exactly (without changing the order of the two functions and the condition at all, Zac - just work through an example to see this), with the slight annoyance of the condition being tested for and used to break the loop manually part way through the loop. This answer also does not limit you to expressions or just single function calls, so on balance this is the best answer so far IMO. Accepting.

Answer (score 4):

I would probably repeat the `doSomeOtherStuff()` before the loop (you have to have it in a function then), but @Kerrek SB's solution is nice too (especially if you don't want it in a function). It's a matter of style as much as anything.

```
doSomeOtherStuff();
while(condition){
  doSomeStuff();
  doSomeOtherStuff();
}
```

Comment: Not just style.  I'm not sure if the compiler would be able to see that the branch is basically useless in every iteration but the first, so you would end up with an extra instruction in every iteration.  If performance is important, you don't want a wasted instruction.

Comment: Repeating a single method call is not going to end the world.

Answer (score 1):

With your update:

If you expect to skip a function call in the first iteration, just remove it from the loop structure altogether.  There is no need to stick an unneeded conditional in the loop:

```
doSomeOtherStuff(); // your first iteration is outside the loop
do
{
    doSomeStuff(); // all other iterations inside the loop
    doSomeOtherStuff();
} while (condition);
```

If `doSomeOtherStuff` has an impact on the `condition`, it should be rewritten as:

```
doSomeOtherStuff(); // your first iteration is outside the loop
while (condition)
{
    doSomeStuff(); // all other iterations inside the loop
    doSomeOtherStuff();
}
```

This is assuming the order of operations is important (e.g. if the functions were operating on elements in an array and you only wanted the first element to be modified by 1 of the functions).  If it is not important (e.g. you simply want to run the functions `X` and `X-1` times, respectively), you can use Antti's or Kerrek's solution.

Comment: It's probably just a typing mistake between true and false - otherwise the two code snippets would be completly different.

Comment: @Constantin It does not appear to be so.  Both snippets attempt to run `doSomeStuff` in the first iteration (only), and then run the rest of the loop for every other iteration.  There is no need to stick a branch in a loop for this - logically the `doSomeStuff` call should be done outside the loop, and then the loop runs normally.

Comment: @Constantin That is the case. Thanks for spotting that. I have updated the question.

Comment: @Dylan Updated to account for your changes.

Comment: the `while` loop is more correct, this `do-while` causes both `doStuffs` be served an extra round.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala If `doSomeOtherStuff` has an impact on the `condition`, that would be correct.

Comment: @Walter:  It isn't repeating code.  It is removing an unneeded branch from a loop while maintaining the original order of operations.

Answer (score 1):

The `goto` is allowed, though ugly. However, you cannot cross initializers with your `goto`. Other than that, a `goto` into a block as far as I know is permissible in C++.

As a `for` loop and repeating the code was done suggested already, I jokingly propose abusing comma operator here (provided that `operator,` is not overloaded for the return value of `doSomeOtherStuff()`):

```
while (doSomeOtherStuff(), condition) {
    doSomeStuff();
}
```

If `A = doSomeStuff()`, `B = doSomeOtherStuff()` and `C = condition`, this leads to the sequence `BCABCABC...` that is identical to the original code; It also ends the first time that `C` evaluates to false. This is if you can write `doSomeOtherStuff()` as an expression. The for-loop by Kerrek SB is almost certainly a better answer however.

Comment: The comma-operator version would still run it every iteration.  That is, there would be no difference in that and `while (condition) { doSomeOtherStuff(); doSomeStuff(); }`

Comment: Actually it is not true, `doSomeOtherStuff()` is evaluated once on the iteration when the `condition` becomes false, however `doSomeStuff()` is not.

Comment: Furthermore, either of the functions might cause the `condition` to become false, and the code would be effectively equivalent to that of the original poster. ;)

Comment: Sorry, I meant that you would be doing the same thing for all but the *last* iteration ... he is trying to do the same thing for all but the *first* iteration.

Comment: No you are confusing things, the code is equivalent to `doSomeOtherStuff(); while(condition) { doSomeStuff();  doSomeOtherStuff(); }` which is the variant from the currently winning (and correct) answer.

Comment: No, I think you have it backwards.  The OP's code would do `doSomeOtherStuff` in the first iteration, and `doSomeOtherStuff` and `doSomeStuff` in every other iteration.  What you have would do `doSomeOtherStuff` and `doSomeStuff` in every iteration but the last, where it would do `doSomeOtherStuff`.

Comment: No, OP's code does `doSomeOtherStuff()` followed by checking condition; after that repeats while condition = true: `doSomeStuff(); doSomeOtherStuff()`. So does mine.

Comment: No, your code will run both in the first iteration.  Only the *last* iteration (assuming `doSomeOtherStuff` changes the `condition`) will run `doSomeOtherStuff` without running `doSomeStuff`.

Comment: You need not assume, whether `doSomeStuff` or `doSomeOtherStuff` changes the condition, the outcome is the same. It does not matter which is run on which iteration of while loop for as long as the outcome is identical.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala forget arguing with Zac. He doesn't understand this. You solution and Kerrek's are the only one that don't repeat either of the `do` functions. This is important.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala As I explained to Walter, without knowing what the functions are doing, you cannot just assume you can shift the order.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I'm upvoting this answer for its value in answering the question without duplication or `goto`, and niftily getting the condition to effectively evaluate half way through the loop using the comma operator, but as you say, the answer by Kerrek SB is better due to its increased generality and readability.

Answer (score 0):

Although I've accepted Kerrek SB's answer, I would just like to add this other answer for the sake of completeness (and also due to the contorted adaptation of [Duff's device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device)). It doesn't (technically) use `goto` and it doesn't duplicate code, though the readability and use of good practice is questionable.

```
switch(true) {
case false:
  do {
    doSomeStuff();
case true:
    doSomeOtherStuff();
  } while(condition);
}
```